# Передача ResultSet в List(Map)

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Пишу свой домашний проект паралельно обучению.
Использую JDBC для работы с MySQL.
Надо вытаскивать много данных с разными условиями.
Вот сваял зачем то надстройку(обертку) для доступа из других объектов, что бы инкапсулировать работу JDBC.

```
 public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> select(String query){
    Connection conn=SqlConnector.getConnection().connection;
    ArrayList <HashMap<String,String>> arr=new ArrayList<>();
    Statement stmt=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    try {
        stmt=conn.createStatement();
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();

        while (rs.next()){
               HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
               for (int i = 1; i<rsmd.getColumnCount();i++){
               map.put(rsmd.getColumnName(i),rs.getString(i));
           }
           arr.add(map);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.fatal("Эксепшен запроса",e);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.fatal("Эксепшен закрытия",e);
        }

    }
    return arr;
}
```

и вариант использования этого метода:

```
  Query qm=new Query();
  ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arr=qm.select("SELECT * FROM users");
  ArrayList<User> users=new ArrayList<>();
  for (HashMap<String,String> map: arr) {
      User tUser = new User(map.get("name"), Integer.parseInt(map.get("id")), Status.parseStatus(map.get("status")), null);
      System.out.println(tUser);
      users.add(tUser);
  }
  return users;
```

Плохо так делать? 
В базе только String и int, ну и Date.

Это мой первый проект и со всем сталкиваюсь впервые. 
Прошу тапочками не бить))

Comment: Лишние накладные расходы на хранение структуры Map, а так же на хранение названий полей. Так же поиск в Map происходит медленнее чем обращение к полю объекта. Лучше сделай отдельный класс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResultSet` фактически является отражением т.н. курсора - [Cursor](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems013.htm), по сути он очень экономно расходует ресурсы, обычно он реализуется так, что хранит в памяти только несколько записей, все остальные данные хранятся в БД, откуда по мере необходимости он подкачивает данные. Если записей много - допустим 100 миллионов, то никакой памяти не хватит.

В общем делать так как вы сделали делать не стоит, ну разве что заранее известно, что записей немного.

Answer (score 1):

1. один метод перегруженный логикой, один метод должен решать одну задачу.
2. ручная реализация работы с бд давно уже изжила себя
3. почему бы не использовать Spring JPA тот же самый для работы с бд, и код будет минимальным, к примеру вот [Spring JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)
4. и ответ на сам вопрос - нет, так не плохо делать, просто есть куча фреймворков, которые позволяют не писать велосипед каждый раз